# How to get name and surname from two id linked to same table SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have i question about JOINign i have tables User and Category and Request

| Id | name | surname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Alex | Morgan |
| 2 | Tom | Brady |
| 3 | Smith | Rowe |

Category

| Id | Category |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Party |
| 2 | Football match |

And now someone create request for another
Request

| Id_request | Id_caller | Id_receiver | id_category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 | 2 |

Now i want query to find all request where user 1 (Alex) is caller and get this result

| Id_request | Caller_name | Caller_surname | Receiver_name | Receiver _surname | Category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Alex | Morgan | Tom | Brady | Party |
| 2 | Alex | Morgan | Smith | Rowe | Football match |

I try with JOIN but i didn't get this result. Pls help.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to join the tables and take the necessary columns.

However, you need to join the table `user` twice. When joining a table twice, at least one of them needs to have an alias. The query shown below uses aliases for all tables.

For example, you can do:

```
select
  q.id_request,
  c.name as caller_name,
  c.surname as caller_surname,
  r.name as receiver_name,
  r.surname as receiver_surname,
  c.category
from request q
join user c on c.id = q.id_caller
join user r on r.id = q.id_receiver -- joined user again with different alias
join category y on y.id = q.id_category
where q.id_caller = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need two joins, one for the caller and another for the receiver.

```
select 
    id_request,
    uc.nm_user as "Caller_name",
    uc.nm_surname as "Caller_surname",
    rr.nm_user as "Receiver_name",
    rr.nm_surname as "Receiver_surname",
    c.nm_category    
from
    usr uc
join
    request rc on rc.id_caller = uc.id_user
join
    usr rr on rr.id_user = rc.id_receiver 
join
    category c on c.id_category = rc.id_category
where
    uc.id_user = 1
```

Here is the complete example
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cA637bx33SFMeDtyUUNqsp/0

Answer (score 0):

You need to join the User table twice with request table -

```
SELECT R.Id_request,
       U1.Caller_name,
       U1.Caller_surname,
       U2.Receiver_name,
       U2.Receiver_surname,
       C.Category
  FROM Request R
  JOIN User U1 ON R.Id_caller = U1.Id
  JOIN User U2 ON R.Id_receiver = U2.Id
  JOIN Category C ON r.id_category = C.Id;
```